# Can I skip the downloading of the Windows support software if I already have it?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows

Yesterday I was facing a problem that Boot Camp Assistant was stuck on copying Windows files but that problem is solved now. After that copying files Boot Camp Assistant is showing that it is "Downloading Windows support software". I have already downloaded this Windows support software on my MacBook, therefore is there any way to skip this process?

Unticking the option is grayed out unfortunately.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating a Windows install disk then you can't unselect the option to download the Windows support software. Boot Camp Assistant, whilst creating the boot disk, will copy the relevant support software into the install media. This process requires a copy of the Windows support software which it will download from the internet.

There is currently no way to use your own copy of the support software if you create a boot disk. If you already have the boot disk, you can just select the option to install Windows, in which case you can use your own copy of the Windows support software.

Comment: I have the same problem. Where is the option to just install Windows in BootCamp?

Answer (score 2):

first download Boot camp software from https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1635?locale=en_US then start boot camp and create or check the first option "create a Window 7 or later version install disk" then at the end it will say "can't connect to internet to download the support software" so just close the Boot camp app then open the flash drive that the boot camp created a bootable windows os (there should be a windows installation files in it) and then unzip the boot camp file that you just downloaded and copy all the content in to the flash drive. At last open Boot Camp and check only the the third option that is "install Window 7 or later version" and continue from this point. After installing Windows, install Mac drivers and other support software for Windows. The support software installs Boot Camp drivers to support your Mac hardware, including AirPort devices, the built-in camera, the Apple Remote, the trackpad on a portable Mac, and the function keys on an Apple keyboard. The software also installs the Boot Camp control panel for Windows and the Apple Boot Camp system tray item.
I hope it works for you.